# How to write try and catch in PHP?

Tags: php, try-catch

How to write try and catch in PHP?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is well covered in the manual.

[PHP Manual: Exceptions In PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

Comment: I can't open the link! Is it working at your place?

Comment: @Ahmad php.net seems to be down. Try this mirror: http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php